# Connecting to database as a remote user

Tags: php, mysql, remote-access

I know that you can access a database from a domain name with a user like this `user@example.com` but will this user also be able to access the database if they are trying to connect via another page on that domain i.e. `example.com/page`?

I am asking this as I am trying to connect from a domain name that will be establishing connections from different pages and sub folders i.e. `example.com/admin/page`, will setting it up with just `example.com` as the ending will all variables of that domain be accepted from the database connection or would each page need to be set up as seperate users on the database?

**EDIT:**

when I say "I know that you can access a database from a domain name with a user like this user@example.com" I mean that you can create a remote mysql user that can access from a domain name, the statement in mysql would look like `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO user@example.com IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;` what im asking is, can this user access from all variables of example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing a few concepts here.

The "page" as in webpage, or domain as in www.example.com are of little concern when connecting to a database.

You seem to be using mysql, so what you need to do is make sure your process that handles some web request (eg your apache server, or IIS, or whatever) can connect to the database.

eg: 
If you apacheserver is running on 1.2.3.4, make sure your mysql allows connections from 1.2.3.4

The webpages themself are not important.

Answer (score 1):

Yes users from different pages will be able to connect.

No you do not need to create different users for each url in your application.

The domain part of the user name is determined by MySQL doing a DNS resolution on the connecting IP. It has nothing to do with the page request to your PHP script.